# Why does this DP solution to the 0/1 Knapsack Problem not give the correct output with GCC?

Tags: c, knapsack-problem

```
#include<stdio.h>

int max(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}

void knapsack(int m,int n,int w[],int p[])
{
    int v[10][10],x[10],i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=m;j++)
        {
            if(j==0||i==0)
                v[i][j]=0;
            if(j-w[i]<0)
                v[i][j]=v[i-1][j];
            else
                v[i][j]=max(v[i-1][j],v[i-1][j-w[i]]+p[i]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=m;j++)
            printf("%d\t",v[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("THE OPTIMAL SOLUTION IS:%d",v[n][m]);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        x[i]=0;
    i=n;
    j=m;
    while(i>0 && j>0)
    {
        if(v[i][j]!=v[i-1][j])
        {
            x[i]=1;
            j=j-w[i];
        }
        i--;
    }
    printf("THE OPTIMAL SET OF WEIGHTS IS:");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if(x[i]==1)
            printf("%d\t",i);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int w[10],p[10],i,m,n;
    printf("ENTER THE NUMBER OF ITEMS:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("ENTER THE WEIGHTS OF THE ITEMS:");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&w[i]);
    printf("ENTER THE PROFITS OF THE ITEMS:");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);
    printf("ENTER THE CAPACITY OF KNAPSACK:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    knapsack(m,n,w,p);
    return 0;
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
chaitanya@chaitanya-laptop:~/Desktop/My prog$ ./a.out

ENTER THE NUMBER OF ITEMS:5

ENTER THE WEIGHTS OF THE ITEMS:3
2
1
2
3

ENTER THE PROFITS OF THE ITEMS:2
3
2
3
2

ENTER THE CAPACITY OF KNAPSACK: 8

0   -72 -1080992920 -72 0   1   -1080993280 0   13403040    
0   -72 -1080992920 2   0   1   -70 2   13403040    
0   -72 3   2   0   5   3   4   13403040    
0   2   3   5   4   5   7   5   13403040    
0   2   3   5   6   8   7   8   13403040    
0   2   3   5   6   8   7   8   13403040    

THE OPTIMAL SOLUTION IS:13403040

THE OPTIMAL SET OF WEIGHTS IS:
```

**Note:** The same program produces a legitimate output for the same input when compiled in the "Turbo C" compiler.

So that leads me to believe that i am not adhering to C standards. Is that so?

Comment: Try to use a debugger like `gdb` and compile your program with `-Wall -g`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you initialize w you are using 1-based indexing:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&w[i]);
```

But when you access it, you are using 0-based indexing.

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=m;j++)
    {
        if(j==0||i==0)
            v[i][j]=0;
        if(j-w[i]<0)   // This line accesses w[0] when i is 0. Missing an else?
            v[i][j]=v[i-1][j];
        else
            v[i][j]=max(v[i-1][j],v[i-1][j-w[i]]+p[i]);
    }
}
```

In C arrays use 0-based indexing. Change your code to use 0-based indexing consistently.

Also, you should check the return value of `scanf` otherwise invalid input will give strange results instead of an error.

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    if (scanf("%d", &w[i]) != 1) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE; // Handle the error appropriately.
    }
}
```

Comment: i know that the arrays are 0 indexed but in this case i am not accessing w[0] anywhere.

Comment: yes in an ideal scenario i should be checking for possible breakage causing conditions but clearly for the given input neither of the points that you talk about are causing an error.

Comment: @guy: Yes, you are. Inside the inner loop that assigns to `v[i][j]`, first time round.

Comment: okay...sorry a little change might have to be made for the index problem...you are right.

Comment: @guy: See my updated answer. I posted an extract of the code where you are accessing w[0].

Answer (score -1):

may be with same code.. including < limits.h > will work.. just make 0th indexed element to -infinity by (array name)[0]=-INT_MAX.

Comment: I fail to see how this could solve OP's problem.  If it does help, please do elaborate on how.